# Globaly request focus on setError()

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way that i can set an **`attribute` globally** and `request focus` whenever an **error is set**?

Suppose i am `validating` a lot of `EditText fields` and setting an Error for each of them, after setting each other i have to request a focus:

```
editText.setError("Error");
editText.requestFocus();
```

*However there exist a lot of fields and i am required to do call `.requestFocus()` in every single one. **Is there any way to set it globally or setting explicitly is the only way around?***

Comment: Creating a function like Sameer Donga said is the best solution. I don't think that there is a `GLOBAL ATTRIBUTE` for that..

Comment: Yeah i thinks also that there is no such an attribute, but i asked to make it sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to set it globally or setting explicitly is the only way around?

No, there's no special attribute in system widget, so you have to set it by hand or extend EditText and override `setError()` to automatically request focus when called and then use `MyEditText` in your layouts

Answer (score 3):

you can create one function for that and call that function in your whole app by giving class reference.

```
public static void EdittextError(EditText editText, String Error)  {
  editText.setError(Error);
  editText.requestFocus();  }
```

Pass edit text obj. and Error String in function parameter.

Comment: I am not asking how to refactor code, I am asking if there is a way or `ANY GLOBAL ATTRIBUTE` to set it once for all `Views` that use `setError()`